# Open Api Generator generate "ResponseEntity<?>" instead of " ResponseEntity<SuccessMessage>"

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi-generator

I have for example this swagger:

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: My App
  version: 1.0.0
tags:
  - name: Order
    description: "Order endpoints"
paths:
  /api/v0/order:
    post:
      tags:
        - Order
      summary: 'Create Order'
      operationId: createOrder
      requestBody:
        content:
          'application/json':
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Order'
        required: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            'application/json':
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/SuccessMessage'
        400:
          description: Error
          content:
            'application/json':
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorMessage'
components:
  schemas:
    Order:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        description:
          type: string
        type:
          type: string
    SuccessMessage:
      type: object
      properties:
        code:
          type: string
        message:
          type: string
    ErrorMessage:
      type: object
      properties:
        code:
          type: string
        message:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
```

I'm using an Open Api Generator to generate code, but this one generates something like this:

```
@Operation(
    operationId = "createOrder",
    summary = "Create Order",
    tags = { "Order" },
    responses = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK", content = {
            @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = SuccessMessage.class))
        }),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Error", content = {
            @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorMessage.class))
        })
    }
)
@RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    value = "/api/v0/order",
    produces = { "application/json" },
    consumes = { "application/json" }
)
default ResponseEntity<SuccessMessage> createOrder(
    @Parameter(name = "Order", description = "", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody Order order
) {
    return getDelegate().createOrder(order);
}
```

As you can see I have this `default ResponseEntity<SuccessMessage> createOrder` but my goal is to use generic type instead like this:

```
default ResponseEntity<?> createOrder
```

Is there any way to tell OpenApiGenerator to generate `ResponseEntity<?>` instead of `ResponseEntity<SuccessMessage>`, I know there are a solution by using mustache, but maybe there are other solution.

#### Plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0-beta</version>
    <configuration>
        <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
        <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
        <configOptions>
            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
            <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
            <openApiNullable>false</openApiNullable>
        </configOptions>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>catalog_api</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/specs/order_api_v1.yml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <library>spring-boot</library>
                <apiPackage>com.order.api</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>com.order.model</modelPackage>
                <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                    ApiUtil.java
                </supportingFilesToGenerate>
                <configOptions>
                    <useTags>true</useTags>
                    <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                    <returnSuccessCode>true</returnSuccessCode>
                    <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                    <implicitHeaders>true</implicitHeaders>
                    <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you provide the version of Swagger that you are using?

Comment: @MaksimEliseev I shared the plugin version and for swagger I'm using just `<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: I came across this while working at a company: we used the Swagger codegen that generates the `ResponseEntity<Void>` if it sees multiple schemas in `responses`. We decided not to describe schemes of unsuccessful responses. It seems to take a lot of effort to change this behavior. I hope someone writes a solution for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am using this version of open API  and it works fine for me what you want to achieve hope this help-

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Controller code -

```
 @Operation(summary = "Get Client By CompanyId", method = "GET")
 @GetMapping("clientInfo/{company_id}")
 public ResponseEntity<?> getClientIds(HttpServletRequest req, 
 @PathVariable("company_id") String companyId){
 JwtPayload auth = CommonUtils.getEmployeeDetailsByAuthRequest(req);
 return internalClientService.getAllClientByCompanyId(companyId);
  }
```

Docs give this -

```
 "/api/v1/internal/company/{company_id}": {
        "get": {
            "tags": [
                "Internal Service - Client related info by companyId"
            ],
            "summary": "Get CompanyName By CompanyId",
            "operationId": "getCompanyName",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "company_id",
                    "in": "path",
                    "required": true,
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "OK",
                    "content": {
                        "*/*": {
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: It is really good that `springdoc-openapi-ui` generates logically correct code, but the question is about `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`.